# Как еще можно задать default-значение переменной кроме try-except?

Tags: python, python-3.x, атрибуты

Объект `obj` - это инстанс какой-то джанго-модели. Допустим, у него есть поле `prop`, которое по идее должно быть связано с другой моделью, но может также быть `None`. Моя задача - записать в переменную `var` поле `target` второй связанной модели.

```py
var = obj.prop.target
```

Если поле `prop` окажется равно `None`, то все сломается, так как у `None` нет поля `target`. В этом случае я хочу записать в переменную `var` значение `None`. В принципе я могу это сделать так

```py
try:
    var = obj.prop.target
except AttributeError:
    var = None
```

Нет ли какого-нибудь другого способа это сделать, наподобие `setdefault` у  словарей?

Comment: `var = obj.prop.target if obj.prop else None`?

Comment: Ну в принципе, вариант. Или `var = obj.prop.target if obj.prop else None` ? :)

Comment: var = obj.prop and obj.prop.target

Comment: @Xander можете пояснить как это работает? :) Я почему-то предполагал, что это должно записать в `var` `True` или `False`

Comment: но  `try:- except ` понятнее. а к такому присваиванию придется писать комментарий чтоб потом вспомнить ))

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров дело в том, что логические операторы возвращают не обязательно True или False. На самом деле, они всегда возвращают просто одно из тех значений, которые соединяют. Например, and возвращает первое значение, если оно ложное, иначе возвращает второе значение. Если вы соединяете с помощью and только такие значения как True и False, то и на выходе получите True или False. Но если соединяете другие объекты, то получите один из этих объектов. Некоторые интересные примеры можно посмотреть здесь: https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/diveinto_python/apihelper_andor.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь встроенной функцией [`getattr(object, name[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
var = getattr(obj.prop, "target", None)
```

[Выдержка из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(object, name[, default])
```

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
>   string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. **If the named attribute does not
>   exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise `AttributeError` is
>   raised.**

Comment: Хороший вариант)